# PHP in HTML with notification

Tags: php, html, css, notifications, echo

I make a email sender, and I want if the message sent, so that the text is not displayed but that a notification box is displayed. I want that if the form is submitted, a notification box will pop up. I do not know exactly how put html in php. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "example@mail.xyz"; 
    $from = $_POST['email']; 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "New form entry";
    $subject2 = "Form copy";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote: " . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is copy:" . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 
    echo '<div class='content'>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-white rounded">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
    <strong>Sent!</strong> Message was sucessfully sent!
</div>

</div>';
  
    }
?>
```

And here is CSS for notification box:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);

body {
    font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    line-height:normal;
    
    padding:0;
    margin:0;   
}

.content {
    padding:0;
    margin:10% 15%;   
}

.close {
    float: right;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    opacity: .2;
}

.close:hover,.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .5;
}

button.close {
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.alert {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.alert h4 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: inherit;
}

.alert .alert-link {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.alert>p,.alert>ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.alert>p+p {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.alert-dismissable {
    padding-right: 35px;
}

.alert-dismissable .close {
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    right: -21px;
    color: inherit;
}

.alert-success {
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    color: #3c763d;
}

.alert-success hr {
    border-top-color: #c9e2b3;
}

.alert-success .alert-link {
    color: #2b542c;
}

.alert-info {
    background-color: #d9edf7;
    border-color: #bce8f1;
    color: #31708f;
}

.alert-info hr {
    border-top-color: #a6e1ec;
}

.alert-info .alert-link {
    color: #245269;
}

.alert-warning {
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    border-color: #faebcc;
    color: #8a6d3b;
}

.alert-warning hr {
    border-top-color: #f7e1b5;
}

.alert-warning .alert-link {
    color: #66512c;
}

.alert-danger {
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
    color: #a94442;
}

.alert-danger hr {
    border-top-color: #e4b9c0;
}

.alert-danger .alert-link {
    color: #843534;
}

.alert {
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
}

.alert .sign {
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.alert-success {
    background-color: #dbf6d3;
    border-color: #aed4a5;
    color: #569745;
}

.alert-info {
    background-color: #d9edf7;
    border-color: #98cce6;
    color: #3a87ad;
}

.alert-warning {
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    border-color: #f1daab;
    color: #c09853;
}

.alert-danger {
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #e0b1b8;
    color: #b94a48;
}

.alert-white {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#FFFFFF,#F9F9F9);
    border-top-color: #d8d8d8;
    border-bottom-color: #bdbdbd;
    border-left-color: #cacaca;
    border-right-color: #cacaca;
    color: #404040;
    padding-left: 61px;
    position: relative;
}

.alert-white .icon {
    text-align: center;
    width: 45px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
}

.alert-white .icon:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    top: 50%;
    right: -6px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    background: #fff;
}

.alert-white.rounded {
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

.alert-white.rounded .icon {
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.alert-white .icon i {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    left: 12px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.alert-white.alert-danger .icon,.alert-white.alert-danger .icon:after {
    border-color: #ca452e;
    background: #da4932;
}

.alert-white.alert-info .icon,.alert-white.alert-info .icon:after {
    border-color: #3a8ace;
    background: #4d90fd;
}

.alert-white.alert-warning .icon,.alert-white.alert-warning .icon:after {
    border-color: #d68000;
    background: #fc9700;
}

.alert-white.alert-success .icon,.alert-white.alert-success .icon:after {
    border-color: #54a754;
    background: #60c060;
}
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what currently happens (since you do echo a message) and what you expect to happen. Be as specific and detailed as possible when explaining. It's hard to help out with an unknown issue. Are you using some library for the alert, or is it your code?

Comment: Btw, `echo '<div class='content'>` is a syntax error. If you want to use the same type of quotes inside a string like that, you need to escape them: `echo '<div class=\'content\'>`, or easier, use different quotes:  `echo '<div class="content">`. My favorite is to close the php block: `?> your html here <?php //the rest of your php`